# The authenticity of host ...can't be established when I connect to the instance.AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2
I tried it and don't know why it doesn't work?

Example:
ssh -i "bruce202101.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-218-105-7.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

cmd：
D:\awskey>ssh -i "bruce202101.pem" ec2-user@ec2-18-218-105-7.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
The authenticity of host 'ec2-18-218-105-7.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com (18.218.105.7)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:9N7GOCZxXLqE5+NGfIykiDDSP8G+jXwLDHHmDaiBhrc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Answer (score 5):

This is normal the first time you connect to a remote ssh host.  As a part of the ssh connection there is an identity establishment mechanism. If you do not manually add the identity of the remote host to your local config prior to connection it will prompt you the first time you connect and then save it to your local config.  Assuming you are connecting to the right server and it is secure it should be safe to answer yes to the question.

Comment: This is correct. There's more information on https://serverfault.com/questions/690855/check-the-fingerprint-for-the-ecdsa-key-sent-by-the-remote-host about how to verify this and what it means.